# Why these queries cause dirty read in REPEATABLE-READ Isolation Level

Tags: sql, mysql, transactions, dirtyread, repeatable-read

these queries causes `DIRTY READ`. I thought that `REPEATABLE-READ` guarantees that the second select statement in `trx2` doesn't return anything. But, the statement returns the row that inserted by `trx1` even though the `trx2` not committed yet

trx1:

```sql
begin;


select * from tableA A where A.id = 1 for update;

select * from tableB B where B.id =2  and B.col_1 = 3;

insert into tableB (id, col_1, created_at) values (2, 3, now());

update tableA set col_2 = 2 where id = 1;


commit;
```

trx2:

```sql
begin;

//waiting until trx1 is committed
select * from tableA A where A.id = 1 for update;  

select * from tableB B where B.id =2  and B.col_1 = 3;


commit;
```

I expected the second selection in `trx2` to return nothing.

to the additional...  each transactions that be added the another select statement just next `begin` doesn't show any `DIRTY READ`

trx1:

```sql
begin;

select * from tableC C where C.id = 3;

select * from tableA A where A.id = 1 for update;

select * from tableB B where B.id =2  and B.col_1 = 3;

insert into tableB (id, col_1, created_at) values (2, 3, now());

update tableA set col_2 = 2 where id = 1;


commit;
```

trx2:

```sql
begin;

select * from tableC C where C.id = 3;

//waiting until trx1 is committed
select * from tableA A where A.id = 1 for update;  

select * from tableB B where B.id =2  and B.col_1 = 3;


commit;
```